# Camel onCompletion is not working as expected

Tags: apache-camel

I have following route in which I want to log only after completing the database insert task.

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true").unmarshal(jaxb)
.bean(SetQueryParameterToMap.class)
.to("sql:{{insertData}}?dataSource=myDataSource")                                  
.onCompletion().log(" Inserted time " + new Date()).end();
```

But the the log msg is printed many times instead of printing only once. I had tried along with **onCompleteOnly** also, but no effect. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing some thing here?

Answer (score 1):

OnCompletion isn't used to determine when a single task has completed.  Since the SQL component runs in the same thread anyway, it will be finished before moving on to the next step in your route.  Just remove the .onCompletion (and the .end).